# How to remove "%" at the end of a terminal output in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I changed the output from "OUTPUT" to "TERMINAL" in VSCode.
Using this code would print "%" at the end.

```
string a = "without";
cout << a;

return 0;
```

But using this would remove the "%" symbol.

```
string a = "without";
cout << a << endl;

return 0;
```

Is there another way to remove the "%" symbol at the end of my output without using "endl" or "\n"?

Comment: Which % symbol are you talking about?

Comment: It sounds like the `%` might just be the terminal's prompt.

Comment: Exactly, is there a way to remove it?

Comment: When you say "remove the `%` symbol", that code doesn't actually remove it only places it on the next line. You would get the same result if you printed a plain newline `'\n'` as well. Do you really know what `endl` does?

Comment: I know that `endl` creates a break. I looking for a more elegant way to hide the `%`

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't actually hide it. The shell only prints the prompt on a new line instead of the same line as your output. The `%` will always be there after your output.

Comment: So there is no way to hide `%`?

Comment: From your program? No. And you should not actually do that, as that will confuse the hell out of the users when they suddenly loose their prompt. They will very likely (and rightly so) accuse your program as being buggy.

Comment: Semi-related: It's hard-hard-hard to reliably remove stuff from a terminal. The better option is to not allow it to be printed in the first place.

Comment: Some shells print an extra "%" after the output to indicate that the program's output did not end with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using different terminal rather then bash:

I've resolved this issue by changing default terminal to bash instead of zsh

**solution:**

inside VScode:

```
- command+shift+p (or view -> command pallete) 

- search for "Terminal: default profile"

- select bash
```

Answer (score 1):

this not a problem,if you lose patience with the '%'

then you can do like this:

with a "\n" addition  "without\n"